# Duplicate jar file Error

Tags: android, visual-studio-2010, exception, android-gradle-plugin

Error

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.

  > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/analytics/internal/Command.class

I added the following dependencies

```
dependencies {
//compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.3.0'
compile files('libs/twitter4j-core-4.0.2.jar')
compile project(':devsmartAndroid')
compile project(':FacebookSDK')
compile project(':libPhotoView')
compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
compile project(':library')
//compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:7.5.0'
//compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:7.5.0'
compile files('libs/gcm.jar')
compile files('libs/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.jar')  }
```

Answer (score 2):

> :app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:
>   java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry:
>   com/google/android/gms/analytics/internal/Command.class

Problem is here

```
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.3.0'
```

You should call one 
Finally

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
```

**Edit**

I assume `libGoogleAnalyticsServices.jar` creating **Duplicate entry** .

So you can comment just this **jar**

**<s>compile files('libs/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.jar')</s>**

Comment: Let me feedback please .

Comment: You can share your answer.

Comment: i dont get proper solution if i get than i will do

Comment: if i comment libGoogleAnalyticsServices.jar this code it get EasyTracker class not found Error

Answer (score 0):

In your `Gradle` file there are two dependencies

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
```

<s>compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.3.0'</s>

Instead of using both use only one

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
```

Because the play-services package is consolidated with all play services. otherwise add separately each one such as `GCM,GA`,etc