# Duplicate dependency error for gms /analytics android studio 2.2rc2

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, google-analytics, google-play-services

My app Level Gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mss.triplestar"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    //====================Add below two line=============
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g" //specify the heap size for the dex process
        preDexLibraries = false //delete the already predexed libraries
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
    compile files('libs/dagger-1.2.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/javax.inject-1.jar')
    compile files('libs/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.jar')
    // compile files('libs/libGoogleAnalyticsV2.jar')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.0.0'
    compile files('libs/nineoldandroids-2.4.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/vungle-publisher-adaptive-id-3.3.1.jar')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.0.0'
    compile project(':wheelLib')
   compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.0'
    //  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.0.0'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5'
    compile 'com.scottyab:aescrypt:0.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
}
```

My log output

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug]
Warning:WARNING: Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5 is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
Warning:WARNING: Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5 is ignored for release as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/analytics/internal/Command$1.class
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 2.579 secs
Information:1 error
Information:2 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

> This is my log output i am trying to build and update my project but
>   it gives me this error if i removed analytic jar than i get easy
>   tracker error .please help i am stuck at this point getting no clue
>   .tried all the solutions .Thanks in advance

Comment: Did your problem got solved ?

Comment: @Spartak Team check my answer

Answer (score 1):

Since you are adding a [legacy version](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v3/) of the Google Analytics SDK for Android  you should remove it.

Remove:

```
compile files('libs/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.jar')
```

Also add the plugin to the **bottom of your app-level** `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Also no reason to use both:

```
   compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.0.0'
   compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.0'
```

and you shouldn't ever be using `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.0'` as that includes every Google Play services library - only use the [APIs you need](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#split).

Comment: Yes I know that but please refer this post it answers the same problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35038141/duplicate-jar-file-error

Comment: Sir @Gabriele But the when i remove the ads and google services dependency than my xml don't get ads view package and gamehelper also didn't work

Comment: and there is also an issue that in my other system this same code works and not giving the duplicate issue with complete same code ..but apk just runs above lollipop devices and crash on pre lollipop devices .

Comment: @SpartakTeam You have not to remove the ads dependency. Just use only the single dependencies of Google Play Services that you need.

Comment: For the crash on pre lollipop, you should check the code and if it is related with the same problem post here.

Comment: sir when i remove any of them than my other package stops working .. :(

Comment: on pre lollipop devices its giving me same duplicate dependency issue

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti can you suggest me any solution . i am still at that point

Comment: @SpartakTeam It is not clear what are you saying. You are talking about pre lollipop devices crashes, but this issue is in building time, not in runtime.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti Sir yes what i am saying is that whenever i builds the gradle and run for pre lollipop device than it gives me the same duplicate issue

Answer (score 0):

change
buildToolsVersion "24.0.2" to 23.0.4

Comment: This will not give any effect .